# Is there way to block uncompress a compressed file using zip, gzip or zlib?

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, deflate, lossless-compression

I want to give some sort of an 'offset' where the zlib will start its decompression from at init,

I have control over how file is compressed.

My question is, is there any block or boundary concepts in traditionally compressed files?

Not necessarily looking for 'random access', say start from offset 0, uncompress blocks A, B, and C, (concurrently or serially), and then in future want to continue from block D, (next reboot time init zlib to start from block D, for example).

When working with large files like 10 or 100GB, continuity of uncompressing helps.

Environments: Linux/C/C++

Thanks for your help.

Apparently gztool and bgzf compression tools can help, but they create index files, as well.
Winzip, zip or gzip traditionally not block or boundary based, not sure if they can help.

Comment: The ability to do this depends entirely on the way the file was compressed.

Comment: @Dúthomhas "I have control over how file is compressed."

Answer (score 0):

That's what `Z_FULL_FLUSH` is for. Use that to deflate, writing all available output. Save the offset of the position in that output. You can then later begin a raw inflate from that offset.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies, 1 important point I missed. At compressed time, i have access to command line, so any tool can be used , but uncompress time, no command line, only zlib APIs or any new APIs I need. Given that, any tool to add Z_FULL_FLUSH during compression? Also what's the block size Z_FULL_FLUSH is placed at? Lastly, when I initial zlib, is there way to set the 'starting next block'? Also I saw this gztool based on zran.c , could I use it at compress time? Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask more questions in the comments. Either update your question or ask a new question.